# ESLint does not format

Tags: visual-studio-code, formatting, eslint

I have simple project, just a few html and js files. Installed ESLint extension to VS code and set ESLint to be a default formater:

[image: setting]

also, this setting is turned to all

[image: setting2]

And here is my settings.json file:

```
 "window.zoomLevel": 1,
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.fixAll.eslint": true
  },
"eslint.validate": ["javascript"],
  "git.enableSmartCommit": true,
  "eslint.alwaysShowStatus": true,
  "files.autoSave": "off",
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "editor.formatOnPaste": true,
  "editor.formatOnType": true,
  "git.ignoreWindowsGit27Warning": true,
  "eslint.options": {
    "eslint brace-style": [
      "error",
      "allman",
      {
        "allowSingleLine": true
      }
    ]
  },
  "eslint.codeAction.showDocumentation": {

    "enable": true
  },
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "dbaeumer.vscode-eslint",
  "eslint.format.enable": true
}
```

When pressing save ESLint does not work on my js file (no brackets, spacing, etc. is corrected). I used ESLint before in React application, so it worked a year ago.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I have found an answer to my own question :)

I got a notification later on that

```
ESLint is disabled since its execution has not been approved or denied yet. Use the light bulb menu to open the approval dialog.eslint
```

So I pressed here:

[image: where to press]

on ESLint and allowed this extension to do its job.